# Use std::list in Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, linked-list, objective-c++

I just found that there's no LinkedList implementation in Objective-C, but I need one. So I am going to use `std::list`(or there's a better alternative?).

My question is: what should I care about memory management under ARC and non-ARC?

Comment: You can indeed use `std::list` thanks to gcc/clang's Objective-C++ mode. You'll need to switch to the .mm filename extension to enable it, and you'll probably want to avoid using C++ types in your header files, or all files importing those headers will need to change to .mm as well. If the type parameters to `std::list` do *not* use objective-C class types, you're fine. If they are, and you aren't using ARC, you'll need to make sure you retain/release correctly. I don't know how it works *with* ARC but I suspect you should selectively disable ARC for your .mm files.

Comment: Thank you @pmjordan, this info helps a lot, it sheds some light on how I can use C++ in Objective-C(I am new to the language^_^).

Comment: What's wrong with `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: Hi, @JeremyP, `NSMutableArray` is great, but I didn't know much about it 1 hour ago, I thought it was implemented as a raw array, which turned out to be wrong. [Ridiculous Fish](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html) tells the truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should manually take care of the memory management, since std::list is a C++ container. Or you can use `NSMutableArray` and treat it like a linked list, append new elements with `insertObject:atIndex:` for the last index, iterate through it with an iterator, `removeLastObject`, etc.

Comment: I can't read the source code of `NSMutableArray`, but from its name, I can imagine that it is implemented as holding an internal array and putting objects in that array, which is not efficient to do operations like `removeLastObject` or `insertObject:atIndex`. By manually taking care of the memory management, do you mean I will have to *retain* each object before I add it to the list and release all objects in the list when before I *delete* the list?

Comment: It may be implemented as a deque for example.

Comment: It's not implemented as a raw C array, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I would seriously try using NSMutableArray first; switch to something else if performance is measurably an issue.

Comment: Ok, I will try `NSMutableArray`. I don't think performance will be an issue for the senario in which I am going to use a LinkedList, cause it will not hold that many objects. Thank you @Wevah, and @Alexander~

Comment: @Neevek You'd do well to read [what Ridiculous Fish has to say about data structures in Objective-C](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html).

Comment: @Caleb，Thank you, Ridiculous Fish tells something really interesting  - *Don't second guess Apple, because Apple has already second guessed YOU. In a good way, of course.*

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use a custom C++ smart pointer (in Objective-C++):

```
template<class X>
class objc_ptr {
private:
  X* ptr;
public:
  ~objc_ptr() {
    if(ptr!=NULL) [ptr release];
  }
  objc_ptr() {
  }
  objc_ptr(X* x) {
    this.ptr = x;
    if(x!=NULL) [x retain];
  }
  // TODO, copy constructor, operator= ...
};
```

Then you could use: std::list>

Or using boost intrusive_ptr:

```
void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(NSObject *x) {
  [x retain];
}
void intrusive_ptr_release(NSObject *x) {
  [x release];
}

std::list<boost::intrusive_ptr<NSFooBar>> list = ...;
```

Comment: looks kinda overkill for my problem, but it's a good answer though, Thank you!